# Why don't servers show up on the server list when I click done on server create in Minecraft Windows 10 Edition Beta

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, xbox-network, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

I click **Play > Friends > Add server > [Enter server data(IP/address) etc.] > Add server**, but when I go back to the server list, nothing is there.

I'm running Minecraft: Windows 10 Edition Beta. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you sure there's a minecraft windows 10 edition (or however it's being called) running on that server? It's not the standard windows minecraft (the one that is written in java).

Answer (score 1):

This is very simply, an unfixable issue on your part. This is a bug with *Minecraft Windows 10 Edition Beta*, and will most likely be fixed in a future release.